# Design by .xib or by .m

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Friends, 
I have an application, ten pages, but full of buttons(with background images), big size background images, box image for set of controls, etc. I have designed all those in XIB files.  It is working fine, but in few minutes, my application shows "Received memory warning level=1". Some developers suggesting me to do designs using .m files, instead of doing it in  XIB file. They are telling that it will reduce memory usage of graphics.

Is it true? Will designing by .m file reduce memory usage? Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check if you have memory leaks in your app?  XIB files use just constant amount of memory. Also, creating the same interface in the code consumes almost the same amount of memory.

In any case, XIB consumes only a definite amount of memory once you load it.
So, if you receive memory warning not immediately after loading the XIB, but a few second afterwards, the real reason causing the memory warning is definitely elsewhere.

Are you doing `retain` and `release` correctly? Run static analyzer from the Xcode, remove all warnings reported, and then use Instruments to see if you have memory leaks.

Comment: The `Leaks` instrument is your friend here.

Comment: I will check retain, release stuff, Thank you for your info that xib and .m designs are same, not causing memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Designing a UI in Nib-file, or doing the same manually in code makes no difference on memory consumptions. The end result is the same amount of life objects in memory, a Nib-file is only serialized objects, no other magic.

Nib-files and Interface Builder only allows you to design UI faster with drag and drop, instead of trial-and-error in code. All the bonuses that Nib-files comes with has a small price; you must bother yourself to at least read the documentation on how to use them! Otherwise you will get into trouble. You can bet that any person advising against Nib-files flat out, have no idea what they are or how they work, and would not be bothered to learn either.

Go to http://developer.apple.com and search for "nib", you want to at least read *"Core Competencies - Nib file"*, and *"Memory Management of Nib Objects"*. Then decide if Nib-file is good or not for your task at hand.

Answer (score -3):

Yea, it is true that you should do it in code. However, if you are receiving a memory warning, it really does not matter. You will have to remove the contents of on page before creating the contents of the other, otherwise it is the same as just using the .xib file. Infact, I once made an application with lots of windows, and I got the same memory warning message.

It is actually very easy to figure out why (I was surprised when I heard). Basically, every single thing in the .xib file is an object. When you have a lot of objects, you run out of memory. What you need to do is run code similar to te following when you change pages.

```
- (void) changeToPageOne {
    [theSecondElement release];
    //Then you make the new interface element
    UIImageView *theElement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)];
    //You will need the coordinates from the .xib file for the CGRect there
    [theElement setImage:(UIImage*)];
    [theView addSubview:theElement];
}
```

You do the same thing for the next page. The problem here is that you will need to be able to keep track of the UIImageView, but it is basically just a local variable here. You may want to add it to an array, and just remove the objects in the array when you change pages. I hope this helps!

Comment: Objects created from code are also objects (!), exactly like those from XIB. Creating in code may only give a finer control, you see exactly what you do, in XIB you may oversee hidden or transparent objects. But that's all, you can control memory as well using controls from XIBs as using controls from code.

Comment: I said something just like that. My point is that one has to remove the objects before changing pages, otherwise they are still present in the memory, thus, you get a warning.

Comment: Your answer states that since every element in XIB is an object he may run into memory problems and creating UI in code would remedy this. Thus you suggest that by creating UI in code he wouldn't be using objects. And this is plain wrong. His problem is not connected to XIB. This is why you now earn down votes - because you have given wrong answer that unexperienced ios programmers may take for truth.

Comment: @Tomasz Stanczak My biggest point here is that he may need to release the objects, but that will remove them from the interface. He will then have to put them back in using he code, so he should probably just use code instead of the .xib file. If I did not make this clear, I am sorry. The reason I said what I said is that it worked for me after a asked a friend of mine about the same issue, and I got this very same answer.

Comment: @Tomasz: While this answer may not be as clearly written as it could, I have re-read it several times and do not find the suggestion you impute to it.

Comment: @Justin: You might try to edit this answer to allay Tomasz's concerns and make your advice a bit clearer. (There are a few typos you could address, too.) Downvoters can change their votes after you perform an edit, if they think it has been improved sufficiently.

Comment: This discussion is a little bit pointless, I know being downvoted hurts, even more if you mean to have given a useful answer. But it is kind of educating in my opinion. By downvoting I lost myself reputation, so if I did it I was sure to have a good reason to do. And the reason was to point out that the logic and the contents of the answer had serious flaws and if based on it next time Justin posts an answer thinks twice about what to write and how to formulate it, then we all have won. He has paid 2 points, I myself 1 point, his next answer will be better.

Comment: And since he's been downvoted 3 times I was not alone in my opinion. Look at answers from Yuji and PeyloW which are just right, it is good for the visitors to see at one glance which answers are worth following. So I suggest instead of discussing the merits of downvoting we just go on with what we should do: programming :-)

Comment: @Tomasz: I wasn't talking about downvotes. In fact, you're the one who brought the topic up <quote>This is why you now earn down votes</quote> in your second comment. Nor was I suggesting that you should or should not have downvoted; that's entirely your prerogative; the fact that you took the time to describe the reasons for your downvote is commendably conscientious. I was just giving my own opinion of the post, because I disagreed strongly enough with your statements to take my own time to do so. This was written on my 5-minute break from coding. ;)